# Using immer with IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, immer.js

I am using the latest version immer(6.0.5) - https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer and it does not seem to work with IE11 . Getting a cryptic error in the console

Is there a work around to get produce from "immer" to work on IE11?

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: main.chunk.js, Line: 137, Column: 21
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: main.58a24afc978a7a5505bc.hot-update.js, Line: 22, Column: 34
SCRIPT5022: [Immer] minified error nr: 19 ES5.

github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/master/src/utils/errors.ts - Says this error is 19: "plugin not loaded",

Comment: What is the cryptic error? Please update your post.

Comment: Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: localhost:3000
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: 0.chunk.js, Line: 3089, Column: 34
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: main.chunk.js, Line: 137, Column: 21
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: main.58a24afc978a7a5505bc.hot-update.js, Line: 22, Column: 34

Comment: https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/master/src/utils/errors.ts - Says this error is 19: "plugin not loaded",

Comment: What have you already tried to fix this error?

Comment: Immer works with chrome not with IE11 - this is the issue

Answer (score 3):

This means you are using a feature you didn't enable first. For example to use Immer on IE 11 ES5 support has to be enabled. See https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/installation#pick-your-immer-version for details.